# Moving element from head to the end of doubly linked list

Tags: data-structures

How to remove node from head, and add it at the end of doubly linked list?

I only have one doubly linked list (say with 5 nodes), I want to remove the first node and add it to the end.

Before:

```
   1->2->3->4->5
```

Expected result:

```
   2->3->4->5->1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just modify the head and tail pointers:

```
temp = head;
head = head->next;
head->prev = NULL;

tail->next = temp;
temp->prev = tail;
tail = tail->next;
tail->next = NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Maintain two variables (head & tail) pointing to the beginning and end of the doubly linked list respectively.

```
temp = head
head = head.next
head.prev = null

tail.next = temp
temp.prev = tail
tail = tail.next
tail.next = null
```

Comment: What about tail.prev?

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay thanks.. I corrected that. +1 for your answer